# Deprecated eregi Call, preg_match Fix Needed

Tags: php, preg-match, deprecated, eregi

I have an open source program I am trying to integrate in a website. I would like to update a code in it that is causing problems with my development LAMP setup.

```
if ($dbselect)
        {
            if (!eregi('utf',strtolower($script_encoding)) && !defined('IN_LOGINPAGE'))
            {
               mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");   
            }
               else if (empty($script_encoding) || eregi('utf',strtolower($script_encoding))) 
            {
               mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
            }

        }
```

I know that eregi call is deprecated and preg_match is what should be used but it gives me a the following error...

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in
```

if someone could fix it and explain why I would be greatly appreciated.

TIA (Thanks In Advance)

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap a preg expression with a non-alphanumeric and non-backslash character (the same one on each side).

So, instead of this:

```
eregi('utf',strtolower($script_encoding))
```

This

```
// wrapped in '#' (# and / are the two most common. I use # almost exclusively in PHP
// so that I don't have to escape the /)
// i = case insensitive, so you don't need strtolower
preg_match('#utf#i',$script_encoding)
```

Comment: Thank You for a terribly fast response, cheers...